# There can't be an entire function $f(z)$ where $\cos(z) = f(z)^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been having a crack at this for a while, supposing for a contradiction that such f exists and computing the coefficients.

$f(z)^2 = (a_0 + a_2z^2 + a_4z^4...)^2 = a_0^2 + (2a_0a_2)z^2 + .... = 1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^4}{4!}.... = \cos(z)$

Omitted all of the odd terms as they disappeared in the cosine expansion.

In the end, I got something like

$a_0 = \pm 1, a_2 = \pm \frac{1}{4}, a_4 = \pm \frac{\frac{1}{24}-\frac{1}{16}}{2}...$ and so forth.

I was given the hint that the coefficients should show some sort of contradiction, but this doesn't seem to be getting anywhere.

Comment: The difficulty comes from the zeros of the cosine. The square root near a zero is multi-valued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer without using the hint:

$f(\frac {\pi} 2)=0$. So $f^{2}(z)$ has a zero of order at least two at $\frac {\pi }2$. But $\cos z$ has  a zero of order $1$ at this  point since its derivative at this point is  $-1 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Another, more advanced, explanation. The function $\cos x$ is positive for $0<x<{\pi\over 2},$ hence $f(x)$ is real on this interval. Thus
$\overline{f(\overline{z})}=f(z),$ as both sides are holomorphic and  equal in $(0,{\pi\over 2}).$ On the other hand $\cos x$ is negative for ${\pi\over 2}<x<\pi,$ hence the function $f(x)$ is purely imaginary on this interval. Therefore $\overline{ f(\overline{z})}=-f(z)$ as both sides are holomorphic and equal on $({\pi\over 2},\pi).$ Thus $f(z)=-f(z),$ i.e. $f\equiv 0.$